# Парсинг вывода shell, хочу полцчить list of dictionares

Tags: python, list, словари, ansible, ansible-playbook

Ребята, кто парсит вывод команд shell, подскажите куда копать!?

- Получаю данные из shell скрипта (обратите внимание, нет кавычек " :

```
 "stdout_lines": [
 "backupsetName: backupset-test",
 "subclientName: test",
 "backupsetName: Test01",
 "subclientName: start9pm"
 ]
```

- Как мне получить в конечном итоге список словарей "с кавычками"? list of dict:

```
"list_properties": [
 "{"backupsetName": "backupset-test", "subclientName": "test"}",
 "{"backupsetName": "Test01", "subclientName": "start9pm"}"
 ],
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Из за того что в моих входных данных нет двойных ковычек, выражение "backupsetName: backupset-test", воспринимается как строка.
А мне надо чтобы это был словарь (dict), значит мне нужно преобразовать это в вид: "backupsetName": "backupset-test",

Comment: Слышал, можно фильтром собирать вывод shell и парсить в переменные? Возможно есть готовое решение... поделитесь!

Answer (score 0):

> Была проблема с выполнением на AWX через Docker контейнер на удаленном хосте.
> При выполнении на удаленном хосте, фильтры не находят пути, и не работают.
> При выполнении внутри контейнера таких багов нет.
> Для этого надо в AWX создать inventory.
> Добавить localhost
> добавить vars

```
---
ansible_connection: local
```

После этого заработали плагины:

```
community.general.xml
cli_parse
```